# What's going on in the Static method in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

in this my code,

```
import A from './A'
import B from './B'

export default class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
  console.log(B.getInstance()); // Why A.getInstance() got called ??? 
}

}
```

A.js (B.js is same)

```
export default class A extends React.Component{
    static instance = null;
    static getInstance(){
        return A.constructor.instance;
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        A.constructor.instance = this;
    }
}
```

Both my class A and B has 'static getInstance() method'.
Here, I called 'B class' but A's getInstance() is called. What's going on here?

Should I avoid to use same method name for static method?

Thanks.

## Edit

I might post my question wrongly. 
I posted a new question to be clear about what my question was. Thanks.

[The name of static method in javascript should not be duplicated? (on React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961656/the-name-of-static-method-in-javascript-should-not-be-duplicated-on-react-nati)

Comment: please provide a more complete exampe. see [mcve]

Comment: can you provide the code for A and B?

Comment: It seems you are defining A class more than once, since A.js and B.js have the same content.

Comment: @EduardoMelo No I meant B looks same as A. Not defining A twice.

Comment: so your B.js looks like `class B` instead of `class A`? and the same for all the references to `A` class on that snippet of code?

Comment: @TheGiantBeast You can change all 'A' to 'B' for B.js.

Comment: I'm sorry to be clear, I posted a new question with full code. I appreciate if you can look that too. Thanks so much. @TheGiantBeast https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961656/the-name-of-static-method-in-javascript-should-not-be-duplicated-on-react-nati

Comment: I'm sorry to be clear, I posted a new question with full code. I appreciate if you can look that too. Thanks so much. @EduardoMelo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961656/the-name-of-static-method-in-javascript-should-not-be-duplicated-on-react-nati

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess you are rendering component **A** after component **B**. As both of your components extending the same parent(React.Component) constructor shared for for both of them. That means if you store anything in as a property of constructor it will be shared with all child components.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
    static setSharedKey (){
        return B.constructor.sharedKey= 123
    }
}
class C extends A {
    static getSharedKey (){
        return C.constructor.sharedKey
    }
}
```

So if you call.

```
B.setSharedKey()
```

and then

```
C.getSharedKey()   //123
```

You will have output like this

---

To give advice how to solve this problem Il'd like to know why you are trying to get instance from static method's

Comment: I'm sorry to be clear, I posted a new question with full code. I appreciate if you can look that too. Thanks so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961656/the-name-of-static-method-in-javascript-should-not-be-duplicated-on-react-nati

Comment: Hi @BrightLee I've answered on that question to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961656/the-name-of-static-method-in-javascript-should-not-be-duplicated/47963571#47963571
Feel free to leave comments if i messed something

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it.