# The name of static method in javascript should not be duplicated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an app using React Native. 
The toughest part is dealing with javascript. I made few app using Xamarin.Forms. Now I'm attracted to React Native.

By the way.

When I call 
`console.log('I should be given B', B.getInstance())`
in App.js file.

I can't understand why I get A's instance instead of B's even though I called B's static method.

Thanks.

[Root.js]

```
import App from './App'
import A from './A'

export default class Root extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <App/>
                <A/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

[App.js]

```
import A from './A'
import B from './B'

export default class App extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('I should be given B', B.getInstance())
        //*************** BUT I get A's instance!!!!!!! ****************
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <A/>
                <B/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

[A.js]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class A extends React.Component{
    static instance = null;
    static getInstance(){
        return A.constructor.instance;
    }

    title = 'I\'m A';

    componentWillMount(){
        A.constructor.instance = this;
    }
    render(){
        return <Text>I'm A</Text>
    }
}
```

[B.js]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class B extends React.Component{
    static instance = null;
    static getInstance(){
        return B.constructor.instance;
    }

    title = 'I\'m B';

    componentWillMount(){
        B.constructor.instance = this;
    }
    render(){
        return <Text>I'm B</Text>
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the instances in your components?

Comment: This is just an example. My only curiosity is that why I get A's instance instead of B's.

Comment: I don't know much about classes in JavaScript yet but from my limited knowledge, constructor is a method and not some trash object you should put stuff on.  So what you need is just `return B.instance`. Where B.instance is not actually a real static class property because JavaScript doet not support it. And you should have just edited your previous question, it's not a different question.

Comment: And I don't know about React (best) practices, but using getInstance makes little sense to me. You should probably write just below your class `export default new B()` instead of exporting your class. Or have some global class keep all references to instances.

Comment: Hi @René I agree I should have edited my previous question, but if I put all stuff there, I'm afraid it would be messy and there is already an answer, so I'm afraid the answer seems to be wrong, even though my question may have been wrong. Anyway, using constructor is the right way to access internal static member in javascript. It could look weird because I thought the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short

**B.constructor** and **A.constructor** referencing the same object *In JS functions also objects* so if change some data in **B.constructor** it also will affect **A.constructor**

### Detailed

To make current situation clear lets forget about React and Classes.
What you are trying to do looks like this:

```js
const constructor = () => {} //  'constructor' is just a demonstrative it can be anything else as other variables

const A = {
  constructor,
  componentDidMount(){ // Again could be anything alse than 'componentDidMount'
    A.constructor.instance = 'A instance';
  }
}
const B = {
  constructor,
  componentDidMount(){ // Again could be anything alse than 'componentDidMount'
    B.constructor.instance = 'B instance';
  }
}

// Now A and B are not equal to each other
// But property 'constructor' in both objects(A,B) references to the same 'constructor' function

//Now lets do what you did, In your examble you was rendering component A 2 times, and B 1 time. A -> B -> A. The last comonent was rendered is A. So what happens at that time

//render A
A.componentDidMount() // This sets constructor.instance to 'A'
console.log(A.constructor.instance);
B.componentDidMount() // This overwrites constructor.instance to 'B'|
// Now if you call 
console.log(A.constructor.instance) // This will return 'B'

// And at the last you are rendering 'A' 2th tiem
A.componentDidMount() // And this again overrides constructor.instance to 'B'

//So after this you are trying to get data from B.constructor
//which will be 'A' because A.constructor == B.constructor
```

To avoid this problem **don't store your data in constructors**.
I think you can handle this problem by using [React's ref's](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)

Hope this was helpful for you

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! It must be helpful. I will look at it deeply and will mark yours as an answer. Thanks again @davo11122.

Answer (score 0):

What happens there, is that when you are referencing **B** in code below

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log('I should be given B', B.getInstance())
}
```

you are referencing NOT the object B you just created in code

```
render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <A/>
      <B/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

but the javascript function B (which is the the class B declaration under the hood), therefore the code

```
componentWillMount(){
  B.constructor.instance = this;
}
```

is 'translated' into the code

```
 componentWillMount(){
   Function.instance = this;
 }
```

as the *constructor* property of the B is the javascript native object **Function**

the same happens to A class, from

```
componentDidMount(){ 
    A.constructor.instance = this;
  }
```

translated into the

```
 componentWillMount(){
   Function.instance = this;
 }
```

consequently, each time you are setting A.constructor.instance or B.constructor.instance you are setting the same object property  Function.instance.

Thus, if you want to reference static class member, you shouldn't apply to a constructor keyword, just use ClassName.staticMemberName, inside or outside the class , i.e.

```
componentWillMount(){
  B.instance = this;
}
```

and it will work out as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. It helped me to understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

That's the whole point of static methods. Static methods are there to share the same method between multiple instances of the same class. (First it might seem there are different classes, but look carefully and you'll see).

Thus static methods are not suitable for what you are trying to do.

As I understand, you are trying to share some state between components. This is a very common requirement in react and is usually handled by state managing frameworks like flux, redux or mobx. (React refs will do, but it's not scalable nor efficient)

For instance in redux, you will have one single state, which will be updated when B is rendered, and then you can refer the same state from App.js or any other component, you name it.